# HTML iFrame not showing text

Tags: css, html, iframe

So I have a page and I'm trying to put all my links on a seperate HTML file and my plan is to use iFrame to easily add the list of links to every page so to change the links I just have to change one file. My problem is that after using iFrame, other text doesn't show up on my page... Here's my code:

Home page:

```
<html>
<head><title>HTML Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigationLinks"><iframe src="links.html" height="100%" width="10%" seamless></iframe></div>
    <div id="mainBody">Hello World</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS Page:

```
body {

}
.navigationLinks, .navigationLinks a:link {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 80%;
    font-family: impact;
}
.mainBody {
    float:center;
    margin-left: 22%;
    margin-right: 22%;
    color:black;

}
```

My mainBody text doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Comment: you mean Hello World didn't show up?

Comment: In HTML you are using IDs, for example `id="mainBody"`, but in CSS you are using Classes, for example `.mainBody`

Comment: I changed it to classes and it gave me more access over navigationLinks (it shortened to meet standards) but helloWorld still didn't show up

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
.mainBody {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin-left: 22%;
    margin-right: 22%;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
}
```

By the way, there is no `float: center`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rCJ5e/ please check if there are other styles that overwrites this one

Comment: I have nothing overriding it. What I gave you is what I have. Here's a [picture](http://puu.sh/7xB31.png)

Comment: Mainbody2 was my code and then I just copied yours directly in